# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.Realm on Android 4.x devices

Tags: java, android, crash, realm

I have a library project that includes Realm plugin as dependency. As in integrate the same library in a fairly large application, my app is crashing with following log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.realm.Realm
```

I read in the Realm GitHub that this can be solved by making the app multidex. But I don't think that is the right solution to it. Is there any other way I can solve it?

Comment: `this can be solved by making the app multidex.` No, this issue was solved on Github by installing MultiDex in the application because that is how you need to use Multidex on API < 21.  And they **already enabled multidexing** with `multiDex enabled` but didn't install multidex, so it was not using support multidex, so their app crashed. You probably have a version mismatch, for example you have two different versions of Realm in your code. Or you forgot to install multidex even though you enabled it. Or you have a misconfigured Proguard.